# Split polyline at specific distance

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net

I am working on a project that uses SQL server for geometry datatype and ArcGIS Server and asp.net website and entity framework for data access and ArcGIS JavaScript API for map viewer.

I want to split polyline object in equal distance for example if I have a polyline with 60 km I want to split it in 10 polyline with 6 km distance and send polylines on ArcGIS JavaScript map api.

I can use T-Sql and C# for splitting polyline.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use ArcObjects for implementing this task. This feature is available on ArcGIS Editor tools. Here's a link :

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-lines-at-a-specified-distance-or-percentage.htm